# How to draw "line from circles" between two points in on Draw and make it zoomable and scrollable?

Tags: android, imageview, drawing

I have scalable image view - it can be zoomed or scrolled. In this image I able to set points with pin. These points are zoomable and scrollable too with the image. But also I need to draw several circles - the path between pin A and pin B. This path should be zoomable and scrollable too. The color of each circle can be various too. Example:

[image]

I creating pins here:

```
override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent) {
                        super.onLongPress(e)
                        pinsCoordinates.add(CoordinatesEntity(e.x, e.y))

                        val touchCoords = floatArrayOf(e.x, e.y)
                        val matrixInverse = Matrix()
                        mMatrix!!.invert(matrixInverse) // XY to UV mapping matrix.
                        matrixInverse.mapPoints(touchCoords) // Touch point in bitmap-U,V coords.

                        val entity = CoordinatesEntity(touchCoords[0], touchCoords[1])
                        invertedPinsCoordinates.add(entity)

                        pinCountersMap["${entity.x}${entity.y}"] = (++pinCounter).toString()
                        RxBus.publish(IndoorPinsCountChanged(pinsCoordinates.size))

                        invalidate()
                    }
```

And drawing here:

```
private fun getPinForCoordinates(coordinates: CoordinatesEntity): Bitmap {
        val paint = Paint()
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        paint.color = Color.parseColor("#1417BF")

        val text = pinCountersMap["${coordinates.x}${coordinates.y}"] ?: ""
        val copiedBitmapPin = pinBitmap.copy(pinBitmap.config, pinBitmap.isMutable)
        val canvas = Canvas(copiedBitmapPin)
        val xStart = when (text.length) {
            1 -> copiedBitmapPin.width / 2f - 8
            2 -> copiedBitmapPin.width / 2f - 12
            else -> copiedBitmapPin.width / 2f - 36
        }
        val yStart = when (text.length) {
            1 -> copiedBitmapPin.height / 2f - 2
            else -> copiedBitmapPin.height / 2f - 5
        }
        paint.textSize = when (text.length) {
            1 -> 30f
            else -> 20f
        }
        canvas.drawText(text, xStart, yStart, paint)

        return BitmapDrawable(context.resources, copiedBitmapPin).bitmap
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        invertedPinsCoordinates.forEach {
            val marker = getPinForCoordinates(it)
            val matrixMarker = Matrix()
            matrixMarker.setTranslate(it.x, it.y)
            matrixMarker.postConcat(mMatrix)
            canvas.drawBitmap(marker, matrixMarker, null)
        }
    }
```

My whole class:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log
import android.view.GestureDetector
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
import com.signalsense.signalsenseapp.R
import com.signalsense.signalsenseapp.mvp.models.entities.CoordinatesEntity
import com.signalsense.signalsenseapp.rxbus.RxBus
import com.signalsense.signalsenseapp.rxbus.events.IndoorPinsCountChanged
import kotlin.math.max
import kotlin.math.min
import kotlin.math.sqrt

class ScaleImageView : AppCompatImageView, View.OnTouchListener {
    private val dirtyRect = RectF()
    private val savedContext: Context
    private val maxScale = 2f
    private val matrixValues = FloatArray(9)
    private var lastTouchX = 0f
    private var lastTouchY = 0f
    private var paint = Paint()
    var tag = "ScaleImageView"

    // display width height.
    private var mWidth = 0
    private var mHeight = 0
    private var mIntrinsicWidth = 0
    private var mIntrinsicHeight = 0
    private var mScale = 0f
    private var mMinScale = 1f
    private var mPrevDistance = 0f
    private var isScaling = false
    private var mPrevMoveX = 0
    private var mPrevMoveY = 0
    private var mDetector: GestureDetector? = null
    private val pinsCoordinates = ArrayList<CoordinatesEntity>()
    private var invertedPinsCoordinates = ArrayList<CoordinatesEntity>()
    private val pinCountersMap = HashMap<String, String>()
    private var pinCounter = 0

    private lateinit var pinBitmap: Bitmap

    constructor(context: Context, attr: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attr) {
        savedContext = context
        initialize()
    }

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        savedContext = context
        initialize()
    }

    private fun resetDirtyRect(eventX: Float, eventY: Float) {
        dirtyRect.left = min(lastTouchX, eventX)
        dirtyRect.right = max(lastTouchX, eventX)
        dirtyRect.top = min(lastTouchY, eventY)
        dirtyRect.bottom = max(lastTouchY, eventY)
    }

    override fun setImageBitmap(bm: Bitmap) {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm)
        initialize()
    }

    override fun setImageResource(resId: Int) {
        super.setImageResource(resId)
        initialize()
    }

    private fun initialize() {
        this.scaleType = ScaleType.MATRIX
        mMatrix = Matrix()
        val d = drawable
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
        paint.color = Color.RED
        paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        paint.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        paint.strokeWidth = STROKE_WIDTH
        if (d != null) {
            mIntrinsicWidth = d.intrinsicWidth
            mIntrinsicHeight = d.intrinsicHeight
            setOnTouchListener(this)
        }
        mDetector = GestureDetector(savedContext,
                object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                    override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                        maxZoomTo(e.x.toInt(), e.y.toInt())
                        cutting()
                        return super.onDoubleTap(e)
                    }

                    override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent) {
                        super.onLongPress(e)
                        pinsCoordinates.add(CoordinatesEntity(e.x, e.y))

                        val touchCoords = floatArrayOf(e.x, e.y)
                        val matrixInverse = Matrix()
                        mMatrix!!.invert(matrixInverse) // XY to UV mapping matrix.
                        matrixInverse.mapPoints(touchCoords) // Touch point in bitmap-U,V coords.

                        val entity = CoordinatesEntity(touchCoords[0], touchCoords[1])
                        invertedPinsCoordinates.add(entity)

                        pinCountersMap["${entity.x}${entity.y}"] = (++pinCounter).toString()
                        RxBus.publish(IndoorPinsCountChanged(pinsCoordinates.size))

                        invalidate()
                    }

                    override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                        val delta = 25
                        val pinIndex = pinsCoordinates.indexOfFirst {
                            val itXStart = it.x - delta
                            val itXEnd = it.x + delta
                            val itYStart = it.y - delta
                            val itYEnd = it.y + delta
                            val tapX = e?.x ?: 0f
                            val tapY = e?.y ?: 0f

                            (tapX in itXStart..itXEnd) && (tapY in itYStart..itYEnd)
                        }
                        if (pinIndex >= 0) Toast.makeText(context, pinIndex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e)
                    }
                })

        pinBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                context.resources, R.drawable.ic_pin_blue_no_middle_32
        ).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
    }

    override fun setFrame(l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int): Boolean {
        mWidth = r - l
        mHeight = b - t
        mMatrix!!.reset()
        val rNorm = r - l
        mScale = rNorm.toFloat() / mIntrinsicWidth.toFloat()
        var paddingHeight = 0
        var paddingWidth = 0
        // scaling vertical
        if (mScale * mIntrinsicHeight > mHeight) {
            mScale = mHeight.toFloat() / mIntrinsicHeight.toFloat()
            mMatrix!!.postScale(mScale, mScale)
            paddingWidth = (r - mWidth) / 2
            paddingHeight = 0
            // scaling horizontal
        } else {
            mMatrix!!.postScale(mScale, mScale)
            paddingHeight = (b - mHeight) / 2
            paddingWidth = 0
        }
        mMatrix!!.postTranslate(paddingWidth.toFloat(), paddingHeight.toFloat())
        imageMatrix = mMatrix
        mMinScale = mScale
        Log.i(tag, "MinScale: $mMinScale")
        zoomTo(mScale, mWidth / 2, mHeight / 2)
        cutting()
        return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b)
    }

    fun deleteLastPin() {
        if (pinsCoordinates.isNotEmpty()) pinsCoordinates.removeLast()
        if (invertedPinsCoordinates.isNotEmpty()) invertedPinsCoordinates.removeLast()

        RxBus.publish(IndoorPinsCountChanged(pinsCoordinates.size))
        pinCounter--
        invalidate()
    }

    private fun getValue(matrix: Matrix?, whichValue: Int): Float {
        matrix!!.getValues(matrixValues)
        return matrixValues[whichValue]
    }

    private val scale: Float
        get() = getValue(mMatrix, Matrix.MSCALE_X)
    private val translateX: Float
        get() = getValue(mMatrix, Matrix.MTRANS_X)
    private val translateY: Float
        get() = getValue(mMatrix, Matrix.MTRANS_Y)

    private fun maxZoomTo(x: Int, y: Int) {
        if (mMinScale != getCalculatedScale() && getCalculatedScale() - mMinScale > 0.1f) {
            // threshold 0.1f
            val scale = mMinScale / getCalculatedScale()
            zoomTo(scale, x, y)
        } else {
            val scale = maxScale / getCalculatedScale()
            zoomTo(scale, x, y)
        }
    }

    private fun zoomTo(scale: Float, x: Int, y: Int) {
        if (getCalculatedScale() * scale < mMinScale) {
            return
        }
        if (scale >= 1 && getCalculatedScale() * scale > maxScale) {
            return
        }
        Log.i(tag, "Scale: $scale, multiplied: ${scale * scale}")
        mMatrix!!.postScale(scale, scale)
        // move to center
        mMatrix!!.postTranslate(-(mWidth * scale - mWidth) / 2,
                -(mHeight * scale - mHeight) / 2)

        // move x and y distance
        mMatrix!!.postTranslate(-(x - mWidth / 2) * scale, 0f)
        mMatrix!!.postTranslate(0f, -(y - mHeight / 2) * scale)
        imageMatrix = mMatrix
    }

    private fun cutting() {
        val width = (mIntrinsicWidth * getCalculatedScale()).toInt()
        val height = (mIntrinsicHeight * getCalculatedScale()).toInt()
        imageWidth = width
        imageHeight = height
        if (translateX < -(width - mWidth)) {
            mMatrix!!.postTranslate(-(translateX + width - mWidth), 0f)
        }
        if (translateX > 0) {
            mMatrix!!.postTranslate(-translateX, 0f)
        }
        if (translateY < -(height - mHeight)) {
            mMatrix!!.postTranslate(0f, -(translateY + height - mHeight))
        }
        if (translateY > 0) {
            mMatrix!!.postTranslate(0f, -translateY)
        }
        if (width < mWidth) {
            mMatrix!!.postTranslate(((mWidth - width) / 2).toFloat(), 0f)
        }
        if (height < mHeight) {
            mMatrix!!.postTranslate(0f, ((mHeight - height) / 2).toFloat())
        }
        imageMatrix = mMatrix
    }

    private fun distance(x0: Float, x1: Float, y0: Float, y1: Float): Float {
        val x = x0 - x1
        val y = y0 - y1
        return sqrt((x * x + y * y).toDouble()).toFloat()
    }

    private fun dispDistance(): Float {
        return sqrt((mWidth * mWidth + mHeight * mHeight).toDouble()).toFloat()
    }

    fun clear() {
        path.reset()
        invalidate()
    }

    fun save() {
        val returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                width,
                height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(returnedBitmap)
        draw(canvas)
        setImageBitmap(returnedBitmap)
    }

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (mDetector!!.onTouchEvent(event)) {
            return true
        }
        val touchCount = event.pointerCount
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN, MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN -> {
                if (touchCount >= 2) {
                    val distance = distance(event.getX(0), event.getX(1),
                            event.getY(0), event.getY(1))
                    mPrevDistance = distance
                    isScaling = true
                } else {
                    mPrevMoveX = event.x.toInt()
                    mPrevMoveY = event.y.toInt()
                }
                if (touchCount >= 2 && isScaling) {
                    val dist = distance(event.getX(0), event.getX(1),
                            event.getY(0), event.getY(1))
                    var scale = (dist - mPrevDistance) / dispDistance()
                    mPrevDistance = dist
                    scale += 1f
                    scale *= scale
                    zoomTo(scale, mWidth / 2, mHeight / 2)
                    cutting()
                } else if (!isScaling) {
                    val distanceX = mPrevMoveX - event.x.toInt()
                    val distanceY = mPrevMoveY - event.y.toInt()
                    mPrevMoveX = event.x.toInt()
                    mPrevMoveY = event.y.toInt()
                    mMatrix!!.postTranslate(-distanceX.toFloat(), -distanceY.toFloat())
                    cutting()
                }
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> if (touchCount >= 2 && isScaling) {
                val dist = distance(event.getX(0), event.getX(1),
                        event.getY(0), event.getY(1))
                var scale = (dist - mPrevDistance) / dispDistance()
                mPrevDistance = dist
                scale += 1f
                scale *= scale
                zoomTo(scale, mWidth / 2, mHeight / 2)
                cutting()
            } else if (!isScaling) {
                val distanceX = mPrevMoveX - event.x.toInt()
                val distanceY = mPrevMoveY - event.y.toInt()
                mPrevMoveX = event.x.toInt()
                mPrevMoveY = event.y.toInt()
                mMatrix!!.postTranslate(-distanceX.toFloat(), -distanceY.toFloat())
                cutting()
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_UP -> if (event.pointerCount <= 1) {
                isScaling = false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    private fun getCalculatedScale() = getValue(mMatrix, Matrix.MSCALE_X)

    private fun getPinForCoordinates(coordinates: CoordinatesEntity): Bitmap {
        val paint = Paint()
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        paint.color = Color.parseColor("#1417BF")

        val text = pinCountersMap["${coordinates.x}${coordinates.y}"] ?: ""
        val copiedBitmapPin = pinBitmap.copy(pinBitmap.config, pinBitmap.isMutable)
        val canvas = Canvas(copiedBitmapPin)
        val xStart = when (text.length) {
            1 -> copiedBitmapPin.width / 2f - 8
            2 -> copiedBitmapPin.width / 2f - 12
            else -> copiedBitmapPin.width / 2f - 36
        }
        val yStart = when (text.length) {
            1 -> copiedBitmapPin.height / 2f - 2
            else -> copiedBitmapPin.height / 2f - 5
        }
        paint.textSize = when (text.length) {
            1 -> 30f
            else -> 20f
        }
        canvas.drawText(text, xStart, yStart, paint)

        return BitmapDrawable(context.resources, copiedBitmapPin).bitmap
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        invertedPinsCoordinates.forEach {
            val marker = getPinForCoordinates(it)
            val matrixMarker = Matrix()
            matrixMarker.setTranslate(it.x, it.y)
            matrixMarker.postConcat(mMatrix)
            canvas.drawBitmap(marker, matrixMarker, null)
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    companion object {
        const val STROKE_WIDTH = 10f
        const val HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2
        var path = Path()
        var imageHeight = 0
        var imageWidth = 0
        private var mMatrix: Matrix? = null
    }
}
```

How to create this path from circles? And make it scrollable and zoomable with other elements (picture and pins, that alreasy scrollable and zoomable)? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If anybody interested, I found the solution. This is the algorithm to get middle points between poina a and point b:

```
private fun getPointsToDraw(a: CoordinatesEntity, b: CoordinatesEntity): List<CoordinatesEntity> {
        val points = ArrayList<CoordinatesEntity>()
        val numberOfPoints = 5
        val stepX = (b.x - a.x) / numberOfPoints
        val stepY = (b.y - a.y) / numberOfPoints

        points.add(a)
        for (i in 0 until numberOfPoints) {
            val lastPoint = points.last()
            points.add(CoordinatesEntity(lastPoint.x + stepX, lastPoint.y + stepY))
        }
        points.add(b)

        return points
    }
```

data class:

```
data class CoordinatesEntity(var x: Float, var y: Float)
```

Of course we can get only fixed points between, cause there is indefinite count.
Here is how to write them. I using prepared bitmaps in array (here is I took 4th index from this bitmap):

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)

    invertedPinsCoordinates.forEach {
        val marker = getPinForCoordinates(it)
        val matrixMarker = Matrix()
        matrixMarker.setTranslate(it.x, it.y)
        matrixMarker.postConcat(mMatrix)
        canvas.drawBitmap(marker, matrixMarker, null)
    }

    //Starting to draw path with points
    if(invertedPinsCoordinates.size > 1) {
        val points = getPointsToDraw(invertedPinsCoordinates[invertedPinsCoordinates.size - 2],
                invertedPinsCoordinates.last())
        points.forEach {
            val marker = levelsBitmapArray[4]
            val matrixMarker = Matrix()
            matrixMarker.setTranslate(it.x, it.y)
            matrixMarker.postConcat(mMatrix)
            canvas.drawBitmap(marker, matrixMarker, null)
        }
    }
}
```